# Read a json file that changes continously

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So... i have a json file that will change after a function happen, im using

`var jsonFile = require('./abc.json')`

But the data won't update until I restart that js file. Anyway to make it update when i change something in the json file using that function

Comment: You're looking for a **watcher**.

Comment: amazing. Thumbs downing my post without even tell me what i did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fs.watchFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) to watch the file, and act on the event of change, like this:

```
fs.watchFile('abc.json', (curr, prev) => {
  console.log('updated file: '+ curr);
});
```

Another method is to use more efficient [fs.watch()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener).

Comment: so with `fs.watchFile` it will keep updating for the js file is there is any changes in the file

Comment: @LeeJingYong Yes, it will create an event, every time the file is changed. It won't update the file imported with require. Instead it will give you the updated file in it's callback and you need to write your logic inside it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you're asking, but it sounds like a custom npm script might do what you want.

First call the update function, then read the json it outputs (&& makes sure it's synchronous)

```
scripts: {
  getjson: "node './updatejson.js' && node './readjson.js'"
}

npm run getjson
```

Comment: the thing that is updating the json file is a sync function that fetch data from a webpage and safe the data into the json file

Comment: @LeeJingYong  You're probably better off with fs.watchFile